# List element remains white space after dropping it

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have 4 list elements placed one after each other horizontally. When I start to resize window then one of them is dropping to the next line and remains white space instead.
HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul > li { 
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/W2A8n/)

 
My question is: how can I remove this white space after previous list element?

I already tried automatic margins, but they didn't work for me.
Thank you.

EDIT: May be problem isn't quite understandable. I did some images to see the problem.
[image: before resizing]

[image: after resizing]

EDIT: Due to nobody has answered the question correctly, I updated this question and pinned some images to the post. Please, this would be REALLY helpful, if you resolve this problem to me. Thank you.

Comment: please try my latest answer - I think this is what you wanted

Comment: I have updated it to meet your requirements - can you please test it and reply back. thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok try this

```
ul{padding:0px}
ul > li { 
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#000;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 -1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GaGSf/4/

Comment: This didn't work also. Make jsFiddle to see , please, if i'm not right.

Comment: Same comment here as to IP ADDRESS

Answer (score 0):

try this? **IT WORKS**

```
ul > li { 
width: 24.5%; /*important*/
height: 50px;
background-color:#000;
float: left;
margin-left: 0.5%; /*important*/
list-style-type: none;
}

ul{margin:0px;padding:0px;} /*important*/
```

please comment back. new jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/GaGSf/2/.

Comment: Watch the last element if you're resizing window. Last element jumps to the next line and remains white-space box without filling. I need to make equal margin between first line elements, so every element has the same width and margins.

Comment: @eatmypants hi I have updated my answer again and this should work to meet your requirments. please test and comment back. thanks

Comment: It's just resizes boxes to smaller size. I need to use straight sizes in my project. So i can't resize this boxes.